# hibernate configuration error

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, appfuse

i had created my J2EE application with appfuse , i want to save some data to database but the problem in hibernante configuration ,this is the exception:

WARN [http-8080-1] ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(143) | HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
juin 07, 2013 5:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet faces threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

and this is database configuration in pom.xml :

```
<dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlDataTypeFactory</dbunit.dataTypeFactoryName>
<dbunit.operation.type>CLEAN_INSERT</dbunit.operation.type>
<hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</hibernate.dialect>
<jdbc.groupId>mysql</jdbc.groupId>
<jdbc.artifactId>mysql-connector-java</jdbc.artifactId>
<jdbc.version>5.1.22</jdbc.version>
<jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driverClassName>
<!-- <jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/${db.name}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true</jdbc.url> -->
<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/castor</jdbc.url>
<jdbc.username>root</jdbc.username>
<jdbc.password></jdbc.password>
```

and if i configure the file hibernate.cfg.xml the server can't start:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
     <mapping class="org.appfuse.model.Role"/>
         <mapping class="com.geviteam.castor.webapp.model.TrajetModel"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: check the answer as I posted.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in jdbc.properties? It should have the properties from your pom.xml and be in your target/classes directory (after it copies it from src/main/resources).

Comment: in my jdbc.properties : jdbc.driverClassName=${jdbc.driverClassName}
jdbc.url=${jdbc.url}
jdbc.username=${jdbc.username}
jdbc.password=${jdbc.password}

hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}

# Needed by Hibernate3 Maven Plugin defined in pom.xml
hibernate.connection.username=${jdbc.username}
hibernate.connection.password=${jdbc.password}
hibernate.connection.url=${jdbc.url}
hibernate.connection.driver_class=${jdbc.driverClassName}

Comment: i think the problem caused by hibernate.cfg.xml when i add properties of the hibernate connection the server stop working

Comment: If you run "mvn resources:resources", does the hibernate.properties in target/classes have the correct values in it?

Comment: in hibernate.properties i find a default configuration for hibernate search :app.search.index.basedir=${user.home}/castor-0.0.1/index
#
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy=simple
hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use=true
hibernate.search.lucene_version=LUCENE_35
hibernate.search.analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer
hibernate.search.worker.batch_size=100

Comment: Removing the hibernate.connection.username and hibernate.connection.password might help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the database connection in hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>

    <mapping resource="com/data/users.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
```

required jars: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar`, `hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final`, `hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final`